# How to correctly deploy a client and server Node.js project using Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I want to deploy my project using the Heroku service.
My project contain client and server folders.

[image: folders]

On localhost everything is working fine but when I followed the Heroku [instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs), I still couldn't deploy my project correctly. I followed this instructions only for the **server** (I added only the server files), but when I open the given URL of my
Heroku project I receive the wild card (*) msg: **Page not found** 
[image: routes]

I couldn't understand what im doing wrong. 
**client** script in package.json:
[image]

**server** script in package.json:
[image]

Axios file in client folder: 
[image]

index.js in server folder:
[image]

**updated -** procfile:

[image]

I added the .env variables into the Heroku config vars.

This is the first time I'm trying to deploy my project and I will appreciate your help :)

Comment: Can you share your Procfile contents as well?

Comment: @Harsh Gupta. i added the procfile to the post.

Comment: What do your Heroku logs have to say?

Comment: @pdoherty926 im new into heroku so i don't know what you mean exactly.

Comment: @guyhazut https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging